# American marrying an Italian in Italy, then move to London

Tags: visa, marriage

I'm an Italian national and I live and work in London. I'm marrying my American fiancee in Italy at the beginning of next year, but after getting married we plan on setting roots in London.

My question is what's the best way to fly her out to Europe?

Since it's cheaper and a much easier to fly to London from the US, I thought the best solution would be to fly her to London, then stay there for a few days, then fly to Italy and finally get married.

At that point she'll apply for an EEA family permit and we'll fly together back to the UK.

Do you think this is ok to do?

I mean, once her passport is stamped at the UK border, she's basically free to travel everywhere in Europe for 6 months, but it is ok to fly to Italy get married?

Comment: "I mean, once her passport is stamped at the UK border, she's basically free to travel everywhere in Europe for 6 months, but it is ok to fly to Italy get married?" The UK is not in the Schengen area, and Italy is, so a UK passport stamp has no bearing on travel to Italy.  As an American citizen, though, your fiancée should have no trouble getting stamped in by the Italians.  At that point, she'll be able to remain in the Schengen area for *90 days* (not 6 months).  Once you're married, though, she is covered by EU freedom of movement and the restriction basically evaporates.

Comment: Also, when an visa-exempt national such as a US citizen enters the UK and gets six months, then travels to the continent and returns to the UK, the second entry to the UK is a separate entry with a new interview and so on -- the previous six-month leave to enter is cancelled when the visitor leaves the UK.  But as the wife of an Italian, this no longer applies, because of EU freedom of movement rules.

Comment: It occurs to me that your fiancée might *already* qualify as your family member as a "person with whom you've been in a lasting relationship" -- I think they generally require you to have lived together for 2 years to qualify for that, though.  It's probably easier for her to enter as a visitor.  After you're married, you don't actually need to apply for the EEA family permit; you can show the same documentation at the border and they'll admit her as if she had one.  This might be quicker for you than waiting for the EEA FP while you're in Italy.

Comment: User Gayot Fow has advised me that you're better off getting the EEA FP inItaly because it will put you in a better position of seniority for the purpose of grandfathered rights for EU citizens in the UK.

Comment: thank you so much @phoog! I think I'm going to end up not apply for a EE FP right away since I can't stay in Italy that long. I talked to a lawyer and he suggested to apply for a FP once in the UK. They told me it can take up to six months to get it and I was wondering if there are easier way to get her to start working in the UK.

Comment: You cannot apply for an EEAFP in the UK.  That would be a residence permit application.  The EEAFP is supposed to take a couple of weeks or less (my mother-in-law got one in about a week).  So you might be better off getting that, since it should allow her to work as soon as you get to the UK.  Residence permit applications do indeed take around 6 months from what I can see.  Also, if your fiancée can qualify as an extended family member before you marry, she can get the EEA FP in the US so there will be less time pressure.